# push_back() is not adding element to the vector? (C++ Tree Traversal)

Tags: c++, vector, tree-traversal, push-back

I'm working through a tree traversal problem and using 'push_back' vector function to update a vector with the in-order traversal. Alongside using this I am using cout to print out the solution to debug. The print output is correct but my returning vector doesn't match the print so I can only put this down to me not understanding how the push_back function works.

This is the function I am using:

```
vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode* root) {
        vector<int> order {};
        if (root != nullptr) {
            inorderTraversal(root->left);
            cout << "pushing back : " << root->val << std::endl; 
            order.push_back(root->val);
            inorderTraversal(root->right);
         } 
        
        return order;
    }
```

For the input tree [1,null,2,3] My stdout is printing:

pushing back : 1
pushing back : 3
pushing back : 2

Which is correct but my returning array (order) is only [1].

Comment: `push_back` does add elements to the vector. The problem in in your code. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: you ignore the value returned from the recursive call  `inorderTraversal(root->right);` is suppose you want to add them to the final result as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ignoring the results from each recursion. You should be doing this:

```
vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode *root)
{
    vector<int> order;
    if (root != nullptr)
    {
        order = inorderTraversal(root->left);
        cout << "pushing back : " << root->val << std::endl;
        order.push_back(root->val);
        auto tmp = inorderTraversal(root->right);
        order.insert(order.end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    }

    return order;
}
```

---

**Much More Efficient**

That said, if you counted the number of local vectors created in this, though short, they will be many (as many as there are nodes in your tree, in fact). You can eliminate all of those middle-men vectors by providing a shim between the actual traversal and the creation of the order vector:

```
void inorderTraversal_v(TreeNode const *root, std::vector<int>& order)
{
    if (root != nullptr)
    {
        inorderTraversal(root->left, order);
        order.push_back(root->val);
        inorderTraversal(root->right, order);
    }

    return order;
}

std::vector<int> inorderTraversal(TreeNode const *root)
{
    std::vector<int> order;
    inorderTraversal_v(root, order);
    return order;
}
```

Doing this creates a single vector, and in so doing eliminates (N-1) temporary vectors along the way, where N is the number of nodes in the tree.

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution, This works. 

Another solution that worked was just moving the declaration of 'order' to outside the function.

Comment: @ArchiePayne globals = evil. do it as-shown above. Alternatively, put the onus on the caller to supply a vector by reference as an argument. Either works, and *both* avoid the inevitable pitfall of globals.

Comment: The solution maybe working, but it is creating a large number of unnecessary temporary vectors - it would be better to make `order` static or pass in a reference to one single vector collecting all the traversed nodes.

Comment: @WhozCraig Just wondering in your inorderTraversal(TreeNode const *root) function, why is it that you don't need the argument for TreeNode const? I thought the function inorderTraversal() was called with 2 arguments in the first function: inorderTraversal(root->left, order); inorderTraversal(root->right, order);

Comment: @hodondo I think you're asking how overloads work, but honestly, I don't understand the question.